# Pass object from JSP to Controller

Tags: jsp, spring-boot

I'm trying to post myObject , with several member variables from a JSP back to the controller in a Spring boot web app. 
Controller:

```
  @Controller
  public class MainController {
      @PostMapping("/myResult") 
      public String myResult(MyObject myObject ,  Model model,BindingResult bindingResult )  {
      ...}
}
```

JSP:

```
<TABLE>
    <TR><TD>
        <A HREF='myResult?var1=<c:out value="${myObject.var1}"/>&var2=<c:out value="${myObject.var2}"/>&var3=<c:out value="${myObject.var3}"/>'>My label</a>
    </TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

The above method works but I have to pass every individual member variable of myObject in the HREF. Also you can't post using a HREF so I have to annotate my controller as a @GetMapping, which you're not supposed to do.
To use a @PostMapping I have to use a form tag and again ,individually declare every member variable in myObject as a hidden field eg

```
<TABLE>
    <TR><TD>
                 <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="myObject" action="myResult">
                 <form:input path="var1" type="hidden" value="${myObject.var1}"></form:input>
                 <form:input path="var2" type="hidden" value="${myObject.var2}"></form:input>
                 <form:input path="var3" type="hidden" value="${myObject.var3}"></form:input>
                 <input type="submit" value="My label">
            </form:form>
    </TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

I have to do this many times with many objects ,some of which have many member variables.
Does anyone know if there is a simpler way to pass an object from a JSP to a Controller without having to individually declare every member variable

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by sending through ajax call and using JSON.stringify method where you pass all the data with key value.

```
$
            .ajax({
                type : requesttype, //Post,Put
                url : url,
                data : JSON.stringify({
                            "var1":var1,
                            "var2":var2,
                            "var3":var3     
                        }),
                success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
                },
                error : function(e) {
                        console.log("Error"+e);

                        },
                dataType : "json",
                contentType : "application/json"
            });
```

Now when this data is sent to your controller it need to get mapped with some POJO like User POJO therefore to do this you can download the corresponding jackson json jar or jackson xml jar to map your POJO and in my case above for JSON you download JSON jar.

and when you receive it do like this

```
@PostMapping("/myResult") 
    public String myResult(@RequestBody User user){

}
```

Remember the key name in your JSP ajax call should be same for your POJO

**dependency for JSON:**

```
 <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not using Ajax or json and the stringify method specifies all the member variables, which is what i'm trying to avoid.

Comment: So don't use it in your form only it will map it to your POJO you can try it work, no need to have ajax or json

Comment: Btw I didn't get "stringify method specifies all the member variables" you can skip the one you don't need just simple

Comment: I'm looking for a method where I just specify the object to pass ie no mention at all of member variables var1, var2 var3

Comment: First of all, your question title should be pass object from controller to jsp since you are passing it in model attribute still my approach of using Jackson bind is easy you need to just pass User object and in this you have all User data which you retrieved then you can do like you asked user.var1 ,user.var2.....

Comment: I have done this the same way you are trying to get but using Jackson dependency mentioned in my answer